# How to access Jersey dispatcher for programmatic invocation?

Tags: java, jersey, odata

OData defines a [batch request format](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/batch-processing/) for bundling multiple HTTP requests together into a single request. I'm working on a web service that must handle these batch requests.

After parsing the multipart request, I have the binary data for each *individual* request in the batch. Now I'd like to route each request through the Jersey dispatcher and collect the responses.

How do you get a reference to the Jersey dispatcher? Is there a better way to implement OData batch processing in Jersey?

Comment: Why don't you just use the client API, and make a network call to the individual services with each individual request data. The two calls could be handle asynchronously